# Is there a sequence of steps followed in chef recipes

Tags: chef-infra, chef-recipe, cookbook

In my recipe I have the following added:

```
directory '/opt/test/scripts' do
    owner 'root'
    group 'root'
    mode '0755'
    action :create
    recursive true
    not_if 'grep /opt/test'
end
```

## DownLoad file and change permissions:

```
uri=URI.parse('https://repo.test2.io/BwIaTHE0ohsUts74LYZMzrt/pair.sh')
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
File.write('/opt/test/scripts/pair.sh', response.body)
File = File.new( "/opt/test/scripts/pair.sh", "w" ).chmod( 0755 )
```

It looks strange, since it is trying to download the file and not create a directory where the file needs to be downloaded tooo.

It tries to download the file to the /opt directory and since the directory is not available it simply fails the execution process...

## ERROR OBSERVED

## Recipe Compile Error in /var/chef/cache/cookbooks/ill/recipes/default.rb

### Errno::ENOENT

No such file or directory @ rb_sysopen - /opt/test/scripts/pair.sh

Is there a control mechanism that CHEF implements or is there a way to make CHEF understand the directory creation should happen first and then download??

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chef uses a two-pass execution model detailed in https://coderanger.net/two-pass/ but basically first the Ruby code that is the recipe is run, which "compile" down to resources, and then the resources are evaluated. So putting a mix of resource DSL and plain Ruby in there means they do not execute in the order you expect (because the `directory` resource was only queued up, not actually run). That said, what you want here is to use a `remote_file` resource instead of your manual code, though in the more general case you can use a `ruby_block` resource to delay running some code until converge time.

Comment: Thank you coderanger, When you say use remote_file, Could you plese explain would that be for downloading the file or creating the new directory???